# Compiler decision to inline function based on size (VS, C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

This [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx3b23a3(v=vs.140).aspx)  on inline functions states that the Visual Studio C++ compiler decides whether to inline the function or not:

```
...the compiler does not inline a function ... if it is too large to inline.
```

But no information is given for what the metric "too large" is. Might be `number of lines` or `size of machine code` or some other metric. This is probably buried deep in the compiler code but some guidelines would be useful. Anybody have a good heuristic for how the VS compiler makes its decision?

Comment: You should not even wonder. You can only rely on what is explicitely specified because what remains can change from one minor version to another without any notice. All you should remember here is *even if there is the `inline` keyword on a function, the compiler is free not to inline it*

Comment: Fair comment as the compiler does its own cost/benefit analysis which is potentially tweaked from time to time. Nevertheless, some general guidelines could be helpful.